# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character  var obj = JSON.parse(cod);

Tags: json, javascript, php

Возникла проблема: имею функцию php результатом которой являться данные формата JSON:

```
[{"login":"11","la":"48.303603","lo":"38.033547"}]
```

На странице сайта работает следующий AJAX запрос:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var cod;
        setInterval(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/1.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function json(data){
                cod = data;
                console.log(data);
                },
              error: function(){alert('Проблема с загрузкой скрипта');}
         });

    }, 3000); 
    var obj = JSON.parse(cod);
    var la = obj.la;
    var lo = obj.lo;
    var login = obj.login;
    document.write (la + lo + login);

</script>
```

В результате выскакивает ошибка 
**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
var obj = JSON.parse(cod);**

Задача состоит в том, чтобы AJAXом вытянуть данные из PHP функции и поместить их в переменные login, lo, la

Comment: Вы бы загрузили код потяжелее ещё, а то в таком очень сложно разобраться. Ответ - пока делается запрос код - var obj = JSON.parse(cod), уже выполняется. вот это  var obj = JSON.parse(cod);
    var la = obj.la;
    var lo = obj.lo;
    var login = obj.login;
    document.write (la + lo + login);, надо ввести в функцию success

Comment: уже пробывал так
выдает такую ошибку

ReferenceError: cod is not defined
var obj = JSON.parse(cod);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот реальный пример на jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '1.php',
     data: data,
     success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
     });
```

Доступ к переменным obj.lo, obj.la и так далее

Comment: а как корректно обратиться к obj.lo, obj.la используя ваш запрос?

Comment: Так и обращаться :) 
    if(obj.lo = 1.3){}
В браузере посмотрите какой объект возвращается.

Answer (score 6):

Во первых у вас `dataType: 'json'` это значит. что в success в  data **уже объект**, его не надо парсить,

Во вторых, ajax и setInterval - асинхронные, код начинающийся с

```
var obj = JSON.parse(cod);
```

будет выполнен сразу а не после загрузки или выполнения интервала.

Comment: @eicto, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: А что вам непонятно ? Мое утверждение основано на спецификации ECMAscript.

Comment: Спасибо что натолкнули на корректную мысль!!
Исправил ошибку!
Ошибка была в формировании JSON строки! (у меня строка обрамлялась в [] из за передачи ее в многомерный массив )

Comment: сомнительно,что у вас ошибка только в этом.